# Remove module.id from NativeScript

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

So I am trying to make a nativescript + angular project. I noticed this module.id and I hear it is old. I was wondering is there a way for me to make a nativescript angular project with the lastest angular?

I want to remove this

```
    @Component({
    selector: "Login",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./login.component.html"


   }) 
    export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
}
```

To be this

```
    @Component({
    selector: "Login",
    templateUrl: "./login.component.html"
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
```

I tried removing the module.id but my app won't compile and just gave errors

Comment: I saw this but doesn't really say much https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/1083

Comment: I'm not sure this is a nativescript issue. If you are using an old version of Angular, then it is a required property for that old version. It is therefore not "old" and can not be removed. So this becomes an Angular upgrade question, and so have you tried to upgrade Angular?

Comment: @cgTag yes, I have Angular 6 on my machine

Comment: Can you update your question to include the errors you are getting when you compile.

Answer (score 0):

try updating everything... reinstall node, nativescript, android-sdk to latest versions and remove them with visual studio code with "Replace All" in find.